# Handling 404 for image content

Tags: http-status-code-404, http-status-code-301

We've recently launched a large website for a client, and have put in place the 301 redirects for all the links on the site.

Looking at the logs, there are a lot of 404 for images. How is best to handle image 404 errors? Are we best redirecting requests for images in the old link structure to the home page?

Thanks in advance for advice on this.

Comment: After googling that looks like the best solution, which I've implemented now. Thanks

Comment: Moved my comment to an answer.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution, would be to make a small-ish image that simply says "404" or "Image not available".  Since the browser is expecting *some* sort of image to display, this would be a better solution than returning some "404" text, which is just going to display as a broken image in the rendered page.